# psycopg2 not detected by postgres django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, psycopg2

I am using PyCharm on Windows 10 and using Python 3.8 - 64 bit and Django 2.2. `pip install psycopg2` successfully installed psycopg2-2.8.5.
My database settings are as follows:
settings.py,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'my-database',
        'USER': 'my-user',
        'PASSWORD': 'my-password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

**my-user** is the user that I am using and **my-password** is my password. However, **python manage.py makemigrations** causes a few errors as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 20, in <module>
    import psycopg2 as Database
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\base.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.db.backends.postgresql.base import (
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Try change django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis to django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2

Comment: how did you install (manually or through pycharm) and what operating system you are on

Comment: @VictorFernandes, I will be working with a geospatial database so I have used postgis. Can I use geospatial databases with postgresql_psycopg2?

Comment: @iklinac, installed through pycharm **pip install psycopg2** on windows 10.

Comment: https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1006#issuecomment-599127025