# Django cannot find GDAL on windows 10 64 bit

Tags: python, django, gdal, geodjango

I am using PyCharm and Python 3.8 - 64 bit. I am trying to learn to implement GeoDjango and Leaflet with a Postgis database. I have a postgresql database with postgis extension. I also have psycopg2 installed following the comments from this earlier thread of mine. [psycopg2 not detected by postgres django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62221751/psycopg2-not-detected-by-postgres-django)
In settings.py,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'my-database',
        'USER': 'my-user',
        'PASSWORD': 'my-password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

When I try to run **python manage.py makemigrations** I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .features import DatabaseFeatures
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\features.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\base\features.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models import aggregates
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\functions.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import BaseSpatialField, GeometryField
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\fields.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .fields import (  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\fields.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALException
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\datasource.py", line 39, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\prototypes\ds.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GeoDjango and Leaflet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line 40, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal203", "gdal202", "gdal201", "gdal20", "gdal111"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBR
ARY_PATH in your settings.
```

I have looked at a lot of threads but I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved from this thread [GeoDjango on Windows: "Could not find the GDAL library" / "OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49139044/geodjango-on-windows-could-not-find-the-gdal-library-oserror-winerror-12) .
1. Basically go to this site https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ .
2. Download the 32 bit or 64 bit package as per your requirements.
3. During installation, select Web-GIS Install and click next.
4. Under selected packages, select GDAL, MapServer. Select Apache if it allows.
5. There will be a prompt to install some additional dependencies. Allow them.
6. Agree to all the terms and conditions prompts.
7. After installation, go to settings.py and add the following before **INSTALLED_APPS = [...]**

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    import platform
    OSGEO4W = r"C:\OSGeo4W"
    if '64' in platform.architecture()[0]:
        OSGEO4W += "64"
    assert os.path.isdir(OSGEO4W), "Directory does not exist: " + OSGEO4W
    os.environ['OSGEO4W_ROOT'] = OSGEO4W
    os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\gdal"
    os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\proj"
    os.environ['PATH'] = OSGEO4W + r"\bin;" + os.environ['PATH']
```

8. Run **python manage.py** commands to check if it is working.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have GDAL library installed at all.
Try installing it and do `makemigrations`.

```
pip install GDAL
```

It looks like you can try the solutions mentioned in this page.

https://realpython.com/lessons/create-nearbyshops-app/

Comment: I have tried **pip install GDAL** which results in error even when I try to install it manually through Pycharm. That thread does not have a solution yet.

Comment: They've mentioned to set an environment variable for GDAL path.

Comment: I could not add the path because I could not get gdal installed into venv.